# I want to parse String into java date object

Tags: java, string, parsing, date, data-conversion

Hello i have date in this format `2013-10-31T19:00:00Z` now i want to display this date into `yyyy/mm/dd` this format.i have used this code but its giving me exception kindly help me

```
String startDateString = "2013-10-31T19:00:00Z";

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd"); 
        Date startDate;
        try {
            startDate = df.parse(startDateString);
            String newDateString = df.format(startDate);
            System.out.println("Date is "+newDateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: show us the exception.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
String DateStr="2013-10-31T19:00:00Z";
    SimpleDateFormat sim=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(DateStr); 
System.out.println(sim.format(d));
```

**output** 2013-10-31

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)'s `parse` method to parse your date, and then use the `format` method to output it in the format that you prefer.

Try this:

```
String startDateString = "2013-10-31T19:00:00Z";

DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'");
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

Date date = inputFormat.parse(startDateString);
System.out.println("Date is " + outputFormat.format(date));
```

Output:

```
Date is 2013/10/31
```

Comment: Would be better, If you write some explanation, than mere code

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're specifically telling Java to look for a 4-digit year followed by a 2-digit month and 2-digit date. Taken straight from the docs, what you want is

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the Datestring. Try this:

```
String startDateString = "2013-10-31T19:00:00Z";
DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:SS'Z'");
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
Date startDate;
try {
    startDate = originalFormat.parse(startDateString);
    String newDateString = df.format(startDate);
    System.out.println("Date is " + newDateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need two different `DateFormat`. one for parse date and one for formatting date.

```
 String startDateString = "2013-10-31T19:00:00Z";

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd"); 
    DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SS'Z'"); 
    Date startDate;
    try {
        startDate =df1.parse(startDateString);
        String newDateString = df.format(startDate);
        System.out.println("Date is "+newDateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dateInString = "07/06/2013";

try {

    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is simple example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        try {
            String startDateString = "2013-10-31T19:00:00Z";
            DateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'");
            DateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
            Date date = input.parse(startDateString);
            System.out.println("Date is " + output.format(date));
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

*Pointing an another simple mistake in your* code
You coded as `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");`

here `mm` is for `minutes` , for `month` use `MM`